# Remove XElement from XDocument

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an `XDocument` and i want to remove `XElement` from this.

Please see the following code , Why not remove the `XElement` ?

xml file :

```
<Reports>
  <Report>
    <Id>45f6bf21-d1b4-431b-818c-c1cb1c9bb221</Id>
    <Content>Example 1</Content>
    <Date>2014/10/11</Date>
    <Time>18:03</Time>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <Id>15c74518-64c0-459d-98a3-831734d96a76</Id>
    <Content>Example 2</Content>
    <Date>1393/10/12</Date>
    <Time>04:00</Time>
  </Report>
  <Report>
    <Id>a2a48e10-4b16-4484-8402-c13a74af3981</Id>
    <Content>Example 3</Content>
    <Date>2014/10/13</Date>
    <Time>03:36</Time>
  </Report>
</Reports>
```

service :

```
 public class ReportService : IReportService
    {
        private readonly List<Report> allReports;
        private readonly XDocument data;

        public ReportService()
        {
            allReports = new List<Report>();
            data = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Reports.xml"));
            var reports = from st in data.Descendants("Report")
                           select new Report
                             {
                                 Id = st.Element("Id").Value,
                                 Content = st.Element("Content").Value,
                                 Date = st.Element("Date").Value,
                                 Time = st.Element("Time").Value
                             };
            allReports.AddRange(reports.ToList());
        }


        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            Delete(d => d.Element("Id").ToString() == id);
        }

        public void Delete(Func<XElement, bool> @where)
        {
             data.Root.Elements("Report").Where(@where).Remove();

            data.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Reports.xml"));
        }

    }
    public interface IReportService
    {
        void Delete(string id);
        void Delete(Func<XElement, bool> @where);
    }
```

my code :

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IReportService _reportService;
        public ReportsController()
        {
            _reportService = new ReportService();
        }
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
           _reportService.Delete(id);
        }
    }
```

no errors. But does not remove the `XElement` . How do I fix it?

I need to remove an `XElement` from a `XDocument`.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC seems irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to refer to the root element when looking for the node to remove

```
data.Root.Elements("Reports").Elements("Report").Where(@where).Remove();
```

You could also just look for descendants:

data.Descendants("Report").Where(@where).Remove();

Either way, the `data` is referencing your entire XML document structure starting with the root `Reports` node, so you have to traverse the tree by any of many ways knowing your first element is the root element instead of the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Xml Linq , whenever we do `.ToString` it represents xml rather than value [here's [MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , 
that means when you do ,

```
d => d.Element("Id").ToString() == id
```

what is going to compared here is

```
"<Id>45f6bf21-d1b4-431b-818c-c1cb1c9bb221</Id>" == "45f6bf21-d1b4-431b-818c-c1cb1c9bb221"
```

to actually compare you need to use `Value` Property , so lambda like following solve your issue ,

```
d => d.Element("Id").Value == id;
```

Hope that helps !!